# How to fill a std::vector<int64_t> with text

Tags: c++, c++14, stdvector, int64

I have a `std::vector<int64_t> myVec` in which I want to store a string (text). My understanding is that i cannot reserve space and write to `myVec.data()`, as this would be undefined behavior. What would be the non-hackish way to do this? I'm assuming the last `int64_t` will have to be filled with padding zeroes.

I'm using C++14.

Comment: But you can `resize` the vector and then `memcpy` into `data()`.

Comment: How do you envision storing text in integers? One integer per character? 8 characters per integer? BCD-encoded? ASCII-encoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are constrained to vector the only solution is `resize()` to required size and `strcpy`/`memcpy` into `data()`

Comment: `std::copy()` to `.data()`. Don't use `back_inserter` because that will append new elements after the initial lot of empty ones.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you store text in int?

Is your intention to store digits made from string?

If so, you shall:

```
std::vector<int64_t> myVec;
myVec.push_back(atoll("100"))
```